# Heroku Dataclips don't see my database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I was trying to use dataclips but when I create a new one, no databases appear in the "Select database" dropdown... (I do have a Heroku/Postgres database for one of my apps)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, created new dedicated database and the first one showed up (and after a while the new one too, which I deleted)

Answer (score -1):

I've stopped using Dataclips for this. Instead, give [QueryClips](https://www.queryclips.com) a shot. It lets you add your own (better-named) databases and saves your google sheet exports.